Does the integral converge $\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos\left ( t^{-2} \right )}{\left ( 2-t^2\cos\left ( t^{-2} \right ) \right )^2}t^{a}dt$?

Investigate the convergence and absolute convergence of the integral at $a\in \mathbb{R}$
$$I=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos\left ( t^{-2} \right )}{\left ( 2-t^2\cos\left ( t^{-2} \right ) \right )^2}t^{a}dt$$

If the cosine is defined from -1 to 1, then $t^2\cos(...)$ tends to zero, which means this whole fraction will be equivalent to $t^a/4$
I understand that this is unimportant, but I have never encountered such tasks before. I would like to understand how this can be checked for convergence and absolute convergence
If you believe me and my estimate (I doubt it), then the answer will be: converges and absolutely converges for $a>-1$

Start with  $t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and simplify

Your intuition that the behavior is like $\int \frac{t^a}{4} dt$ is good. To check more formally, we can consider $\int_0^\delta \frac{|\cos(t^{-2})|}{(2-t^2\cos(t^{-2}))^2} t^a, dt$ and try to show it either approaches zero or not (non-zero limit or no limit) when $\delta \to 0^+$.

Could you show this?

Not everything is so simple with this integral

Can someone show how this task is solved? I get a different answer every time

@Dmitry if you have attempted solutions, adding details on what you've tried (even if it failed/gave different answers) can help others answering your question.

Let $x=1/t^2\Rightarrow t=1/\sqrt{x}$, $x>0$. Then
$$I=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos\left ( t^{-2} \right )}{\left ( 2-t^2\cos \left ( t^{-2} \right ) \right )}t^{\alpha }dt=-\int\limits_{\infty }^{1}\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{x^{3/2}}\cdot \frac{\cos x}{\left ( 2-1/x\cos x \right )^2}\frac{dx}{x^{1/2\alpha }}=$$
$$=\int\limits_{1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{x^{3/2+1/2\alpha }}\cdot \frac{\cos x}{\left ( 2-1/x\cos x \right )^2}dx$$
We will check by Dirichlet
Let $f(x)=\cos x$ and $g(x)=\cfrac{1}{x^{3/2+1/2\alpha }}\cdot \cfrac{1}{\left ( 2-1/x\cos x \right )^2}$

$\displaystyle{\left | \int\limits_{1}^{t}\cos tdt \right |}=\left | \sin t-\sin 1 \right |<2\Rightarrow f(x)\text{ limited }$
$\cfrac{1}{x^{3/2+1/2\alpha }}\cdot \cfrac{1}{\left ( 2-1/x\cos x \right )^2}\sim \cfrac{1}{x^{3/2+1/2\alpha }}\longrightarrow \begin{cases}
0, \text{ if } \cfrac{3}{2}+\cfrac{1}{2}\alpha >0\\ 
1, \text{ if } \cfrac{3}{2}+\cfrac{1}{2}=0\\
\infty, \text{ if } \cfrac{3}{2}+\cfrac{1}{2}<0
\end{cases}$
$g(x)\downdownarrows $

We conclude that for $\alpha >-3$ the integral is Dirichlet convergent. Now, according to Cauchy, we will show that as $a\leq -3$ the integral diverges, that is
$$\exists x_0:\forall x>x_0 \; g(x)\geq \frac{1}{2} \quad \left | \int\limits_{\xi _1}^{\xi _2}g(x)\cos xdx \right |\geq \frac{1}{2}\left | \int\limits_{\xi _1}^{\xi _2}\cos xdx \right |$$
$$\exists \Sigma =1:\forall \eta \geq 1:\begin{matrix}
\Sigma \xi _1=\cfrac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k\\ 
\Sigma \xi _2=-\cfrac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k
\end{matrix} \quad \left | \int\limits_{\xi _1}^{\xi _2}\cos xdx \right |\geq 1$$
We have shown that for $\alpha \leq -3$ the integral diverges. Now let's look at absolute convergence
$$\left | \frac{1}{x^{3/2+1/2\alpha }}\cdot \frac{\cos x}{\left ( 2-1/x\cos x \right )^2} \right |\leq \left | \frac{1}{x^{3/2+1/2\alpha }} \right |, \; \frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\alpha >1$$
Let us solve this inequality and find that $1/2\alpha >-1/2\Rightarrow a>-1$ converges absolutely. So it remains to check for conditional convergence
$$\left | \frac{1}{x^{3/2+1/2\alpha }}\cdot \frac{\cos x}{\left ( 2-1/x\cos x \right )^2} \right |\geq \left | \frac{1}{x^{3/2+1/2\alpha }}\cdot \frac{\cos^2x}{\left ( 2-1/x\cos x \right )^2} \right |=$$
$$=\left | \frac{1}{x^{3/2+1/2\alpha }\left ( 2-1/x\cos x \right )^2}+\frac{\cos 2x}{2\left ( 2-1/x\cos x \right )^2}\cdot \frac{1}{x^{3/2+1/2\alpha }} \right |$$
Diverges at $\alpha \in (-3,1]$
